# How should I reduce repetition in rust type signatures?

Tags: rust

I have the following working code that isn't very DRY:

```rust
impl<'a, G, E, N, EW, NW, ER, NOW, EOW> Overlay<'a, G, E, N, EW, NW, ER, NOW, EOW>
where
    &'a G: GraphBase<EdgeId = E, NodeId = N> +
           Data<EdgeWeight = EW, NodeWeight = NW> +
           DataMap,
    ER: EdgeRef<Weight = EW, EdgeId = E, NodeId = N>,
    E: Copy + Eq + Hash,
    N: Copy + Eq + Hash,
{
    fn overlayed_elements(&'a self) -> OverlayedItems<'a, G, E, N, EW, NW, ER, NOW, EOW>{
        OverlayedItems{
            overlay: self,
            phase: Phase::Nodes(self.nodes.iter()),
            node_indexes: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }
    pub fn overlay_edge<'b>(&'b mut self, edge: ER, eow: EOW) {
        self.edges.insert(edge.id(), eow);
        self.edge_refs.insert(edge.id(), edge);
    }
    pub fn overlay_node<'b>(&'b mut self, node: N, now: NOW) {
        self.nodes.insert(node, now);
    }
    fn remove_edge<'b>(&'b mut self, edge: E) {
        self.edges.remove(&edge);
        self.edge_refs.remove(&edge);
    }
    fn remove_node<'b>(&'b mut self, node: N) {
        self.nodes.remove(&node);
    }
}
```

[context](https://render.githubusercontent.com/view/ipynb?commit=1984cf61bfc30b56f5164c0ca75998793be65fe3&enc_url=68747470733a2f2f7261772e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f74696d7468656c696f6e2f727573742d6a7570797465722f313938346366363162666333306235366635313634633063613735393938373933626536356665332f77616c6b2d74726565732d70617274322d77616c6b732e6970796e62&nwo=timthelion%2Frust-jupyter&path=walk-trees-part2-walks.ipynb&repository_id=219850454&repository_type=Repository#Walk-trees-part-2:-walks-and-selections)

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=be7baf4c7d9a13f646992f88eae93673)

I have a lot of repetition of `<'a, G, E, N, EW, NW, ER, NOW, EOW>` and it generally seems that all these trait thingamagigs are taking up a lot of space. Is this just bad code, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Associated types (e.g. `EdgeId` and `NodeId` in the `GraphBase` trait) don't always need to be specified. See if you can remove `E`, `N`, `EW` and  `NW` from the impl. I haven't tested this, but you should be able to use these types by writing `G::EdgeId` etc.

Comment: A [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/) for experimentation would be great!

Comment: I just added a playground link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Associated types do not always need to have their own type parameters. For example, you can write `G::EdgeId` in a bound instead of having a separate parameter `E`.

I adjusted the code in the playground link to reduce the number of type arguments. Here's the [updated link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a4d189191a0e7a949521b3e96315eea8). For example, `Overlay` now has 4 instead of 8 type arguments:

```
pub struct Overlay<G, ER, NOW, EOW>
where
    G: GraphBase + Data,
    ER: EdgeRef<Weight = G::EdgeWeight, EdgeId = G::EdgeId, NodeId = G::NodeId>,
{
    nodes: HashMap<G::NodeId, NOW>,
    edges: HashMap<G::EdgeId, EOW>,
    edge_refs: HashMap<G::EdgeId, ER>,
    graph: G,
}
```

Note that I removed the (unnecessary) `Copy + Eq + Hash` trait bounds for `G::NodeId` and `G::EdgeId`. Also, `G` is no longer behind a reference in the trait bounds, which might cause lifetime issues, but these can be fixed if necessary.

Comment: I had to do a bit of fiddling so that I had a reference to a graph rather than a copy of the graph in Overlay, but this is much better. I was even able to get rid of the ER parameter too! https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=63905b2f4205317a17efae3fa5d47ede

Comment: @timthelion Actually, you can still store a reference to the graph in my solution, if you use something like `Overlay<&Graph, _, _, _>`, since `&Graph` implements the `GraphBase` trait.