# Is there a good way to represent trait bounds for trait placeholder type?

Tags: rust

Today, I write a code with generics and TryFrom trait like below.

```
fn foo<A, B, C>(a: A) -> B 
  where B: TryFrom<A, Error=C>,
        C: std::fmt::Debug,
{
  B::try_from(a).unwrap()
}
```

I can compile this code.

However, type parameter, C, feels me very redundant and I think there is more good way to represent above code like below.

```
fn foo<A, B>(a: A) -> B
  where B: TryFrom<A, Error = _ where std::fmt::Debug>
{
  B::try_from(a).unwrap()
}
```

However, this code is rejected by compiler.

Is there a way to represent the code like second code to remove wasted type parameter?

Comment: Coincidentally, this question was just recently answered as [How should I reduce repetition in rust type signatures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60792494/how-should-i-reduce-repetition-in-rust-type-signatures)

Comment: Applied to your case: `fn foo<A, B>(a: A) -> B where B: TryFrom<A>, B::Error: std::fmt::Debug`